# Use Webdav on Linux to get a file from SkyDrive *without* mounting

Tags: python, linux, webdav, onedrive

I want to download a file from SkyDrive programmatically using Python on Linux.

I can't use the API as it's a OneNote file and [the API can't be used to download these](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-skydrive/issues/2).

My understanding is that SD supports Webdav and there are plenty of examples where people have mounted an SD folder using davfs2 but I just want to be able to grab a specific file without mounting.

I can use the API to get the document owner's cid so don't need to [jump through any windows based hoops](http://blog.lazut.in/2012/12/skydrive-webdav-access.html) but my - probably lame, have not really researched webdav - efforts to download the file always resort in an error.

For example using easywebdav:

```
import easywebdav
webdav = easywebdav.connect("d.docs.live.net/mycid")

webdav.download('me/skydrive/Documents/Getting\ Started', '/tmp/foo')
#this gives the 302 error mentioned in the comments at the end of the the 'jumping through windows hoops' link I posted above.
```

Is there any workaround for the redirection problem I've seen mentioned?

Do I have this wrong and when accessing files on a webdav share it makes sense, and indeed it's essential, to mount it as a file system?

Answer (score 1):

If you are downloading a specific file, and already know the exact path/URL to that file (as per your example), I'm not sure that you really need to worry about the DAV extensions. Have you tried downloading the file using a simple HTTP GET, through something like [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)?

Comment: Useful, thanks. 

Using the link that one can read from the document metadata using the API urllib2 did actually download something. Unfortunately it's not the file (but that's a different problem related to how Skydrive handles Skydrive documents). 

I was hoping that using Webdav it might actually give me the target file not the placeholder for the file.

I think I'll tinker with Cadaver to see if I can get it using the CLI.